# app not running in ipad simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I have a taken a application (*.app) from a jail broken ipad. I am not able to run that ipad application in iphone simulator(ipad 3.2). Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add some more details, what issue you have faced in installation, are there any logs of that? Be precise in question.

Comment: No,I dont have any logs. I just took folder named "A24E02D7-2215-410C-9C1D-F750FDDAE6F5" from jail broken ipad and added them to "users/username/library/app support/iphone simulator/<ios version>/apps/" directory, next i launched iphone simulator and clicked on the app that i have installed. the app does not respond to clicks.

Comment: Samfisher is right, build for device and simulator are different, so device builds will not work for simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simulator and device builds are separate. you need to try it on device rather than a simulator.